# Question about a specific grammatical feature

Tags: grammar, verbs, list-of-languages, constructed-language

In one Conlang I am developing there is a feature where owned items are treated as the subject of a verb, and the owner as the Object.

So, for example:

Car *sohi* Amelia

Would mean Amelia's Car, with *Sohi* being a verb approximating to "is owned by",

Are there any natural languages that have a similar feature? Or is it even a plausible grammatical development to begin with?

Comment: Note there is [conlang.se] for conlanging questions (but this doesn't make the question off-topic here).

Comment: Ah, thank you, that is helpful for my questions directly relating to Conlanging.

Answer (score 0):

In Latin the owner was in the dative case and the owned in the nominative case, as in the phrase

*Mihi est amicus*

To-me is a-friend

"I have a friend"

In German, the verb *gehören* uses a similar construction:

*Das Auto gehört mir*

The car belongs to-me

... and even the English verb *belong* fits in the same pattern.

The German and English examples are certainly **marked** and a construction with *haben* (German) or *have* or *own* (English) is the plain and common one.

Comment: Yeah, that should have been obvious, thanks for your help. I feel a bit dumb for slipping on that.

Comment: No need to worry. We are always kind of linguistically blind to the features of our first language.

Comment: Note how _belong_ in English has become the preposition _bilong_ in Tok Pisin, which is the [principal way to indicate possession](https://www.tokpisin.info/bilong/).

Comment: In Russian, Welsh, Irish, and Hebrew (to name but four) the normal translation of _I have a book_ is _A book is to/at/with me_.

Comment: The examples given here are slightly different, or at least feel slightly different to me. The possessor is not really an object as such – it’s dative (or prepositional) in the examples here (though not in Scandinavian), can’t be passivised (even in Scandinavian; _*jeg tilhøres af bilen_ is meaningless), etc.